# Syntax error with a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I was writing a program that would give the tabular form of the number of food items available. Here’s the code:

```
def kiwi(headline,leftwidth,rightwidth):
  print(str(headline).center(leftwidth+rightwidth,'-'))
  for k,v in List.items():
    print((str(k).ljust(leftwidth,'.') + str(v).rjust(rightwidth))

List={'sandwiches': 4, 'apples': 12, 'cups': 4, 'cookies': 8000}

kiwi(PICNIC ITEMS AVAILABLE,12,5)
```

I expected it to look something like this:

[image]

When I run this I get a syntax error in `List` ( the second last line ). I think that I have typed all the parenthesis correct then why am I getting this error?

Also if you see another bug in the code, please tell me about that too!

EDIT: In respond to some answers, here’s the code in sublime text. See, everything seems fine

[image]

Comment: Count the parentheses on the line above.

Comment: You didn't close the print statement above "List", which is a `dict`. ;)

Comment: @DanielRoseman 2!?

Comment: Yes, so where is the second one closed?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ , I closed it.But still, Python pops up a syntax error

Comment: @DanielRoseman I closed it.But still, Python pops up a syntax error

Comment: @AaryanDewan It looks like you're using a special character single quotation, `’`, instead of `'`.

Comment: what is `kiwi(PICNIC ITEMS AVAILABLE,12,5)`

Comment: @JohnSmith , kiwi is the name of the function

Comment: You can check my answer below then. So you just missed the quotes and a parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close the parenthesis on line 4. The second mistake is, on 2 and 4 lines, `’` is used instead of `'`.

It's your original code, on that, even you can see what's wrong from its *color*.

```
                                                //|
def kiwi(headline,leftwidth,rightwidth):        //v
  print(str(headline).center(leftwidth+rightwidth,’-'))
  for k,v in List.items():  // <--
    print((str(k).ljust(leftwidth,’.’) + str(v).rjust(rightwidth))

List={'sandwiches': 4, 'apples': 12, 'cups': 4, 'cookies': 8000}

kiwi(PICNIC ITEMS AVAILABLE,12,5)
```

Edit, 
you've said I'm using *Sublime Text*, however, it indicates at least the apostrophe error.

[image]

Edit 2, what about parenthesis?

[image]

Comment: See the edited question!

Comment: edit the code as code as well as image. @AaryanDewan

Comment: @AaryanDewan see edited answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked. The problem was with the parenthesis!

Answer (score 1):

This should be better :

```
def kiwi(headline,leftwidth,rightwidth, items_av):
  print(str(headline).center(leftwidth+rightwidth,'-'))
  for k,v in items_av.items():
    print((str(k).ljust(leftwidth,'.') + str(v).rjust(rightwidth))

items_av={'sandwiches': 4, 'apples': 12, 'cups': 4, 'cookies': 8000}

kiwi("PICNIC ITEMS AVAILABLE",12,5, items_av)
```

There was a few issues in your code, please compare with your version

Answer (score 1):

You made some, mistakes on parentheses and on string identifiers ('). You used a ` instead of a ' several times.

This will work:

```
def kiwi(headline,leftwidth,rightwidth):
  print(str(headline).center(leftwidth+rightwidth,'-'))
  for k,v in List.items():
    print((str(k).ljust(leftwidth,'.') + str(v).rjust(rightwidth)))

List={'sandwiches': 4, 'apples': 12, 'cups': 4, 'cookies': 8000}

kiwi("PICNIC ITEMS AVAILABLE",12,5)
```

A hint: Use an editor with proper syntax higlighting such as "geany" on Linux or "Notepad++" on Windows. Then these mistakes are much less likely to happen.

Comment: I am using sublime text and the parentheses that I use is ' . Is this wrong?

Comment: No ' is not wrong. But you used ’ instead of ' in lines 2 and 4. Strings **must** always be enclosed by either double quotes (") or single quotes ('). But I understand your difficulties, it is sometimes hard to see the difference.

Comment: Please see the edited question

Answer (score 1):

You just need the quotes in `kiwi` function:

```
def kiwi(headline,leftwidth,rightwidth):
    print(str(headline).center(leftwidth+rightwidth,'*'))
    for k,v in List.items():
            print(str(k).ljust(leftwidth,'-') + str(v).rjust(rightwidth))

List={'sandwiches': 4, 'apples': 12, 'cups': 4, 'cookies': 8000}

kiwi("PICNIC ITEMS AVAILABLE", 12, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

HaHaHa, lots of answer. And here is one more.

For better sorting for the data you provides, use `type(list)` instead of `type(dict)`

And the following code can show what you wants.

```
def kiwi(headline, leftwidth, rightwidth, items):
    print(str(headline).center(leftwidth+rightwidth, '-'))
    for k, v in items:
        print(str(k).ljust(leftwidth, '.') + str(v).rjust(rightwidth))

items_av = [('sandwiches', 4), ('apples', 12), ('cups', 4), ('cookies', 8000)]
kiwi("PICNIC ITEMS", 21, 5, items_av)
```